# Dismiss UIAlertView on Xcode 5 and iOS 8

Tags: ios, uialertview, ios8, uialertviewdelegate, uialertcontroller

My app is ready to go to the App Store, so I'm still using Xcode 5 at the moment.
However, when I installed it on my `iPad` with `iOS 8` there was a strange problem.

I create an Alert just fine with delegate:self. But the function to dismiss the alert is just not working (it's in another method and working fine on all other devices).

I tried:

```
[alertLaden dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:[alertLaden cancelButtonIndex] animated:YES];
```

and NO

```
[alertLaden dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

and NO

```
[alertLaden dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
```

and NO

Anybody with the same problem?

Comment: it seems your application is not such ready yet.

Comment: You're manually dismissing the alert ? Surely when they click on of the buttons on the alert it will hide

Comment: Is `alertLaden` set when you run it on iOS 8?

Comment: @CW0007007, there are some situations when there is no button on the `UIAlertView`, and it has to be dismissed programmatically e.g. after a longer procedure or calculation.

Comment: iOS8 is still beta, so if it works correctly on iOS 7 then you have two choices - 1 release now and either hope that it is an iOS8 bug that is relaxed or release a new version when iOS8 ships or 2 wait for iOS8 to ship and figure out how to get it working by then

Comment: Thanks for the answers! The alert does not have any buttons. It is dissmissed when a method is done (yes the method Will get done on ios 8 too, I tested that). [alertLaden show] is in the viewDidLoad. Maybe it is indeed because ios 8 is in beta..

Comment: its important to discern between UIAlertview (& UIActionSheet) being deprecated for Xcode 6, and not iOS8 as the likes of Erica Sadun would have us believe. Apps with Alerts written in Xcode 5, already shipped and working on iOS7 will work fine. But for those using Swift means they can only ship from Xcode 6, well then life becomes complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 8 Apple is trying to switch to [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertController/addAction:) instead of [UIAlertView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertView) and [UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIActionSheet).

From UIAlertController documentation:

> A UIAlertController object displays an alert message to the user. This class replaces the UIActionSheet and UIAlertView classes for displaying alerts.

However, Apple does not state in UIAlertView and UIActionSheet that they are deprecated. 
Using UIActionSheet I got warnings in Xcode 6, which were resolved when switching to UIAlertController.

Comment: Thnx that makes sense!!